# What would be the solution of $ y''+y=\cos (ax) \ $ if $ \ a \to 1 \ $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What would be the solution of $ y''+y=\cos (ax) \ $ if $ \ a \to 1 \ $.

**Answer:**

I have found the complementary function $ y_c \ $

$ y_c(x)=A \cos x+B \sin x \ $

But How can I find the particular integral if $ a \to 1 \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity let's just solve the complex exponential problem $z''+z=e^{iax}$ (your solution is the real part of this). When $a \neq 1$, the particular solution to this is of the form $Ae^{iax}$ (where $A$ is in general complex). When $a=1$ this is no longer a particular solution, because it is actually a homogeneous solution. Instead the particular solution looks like $Axe^{ix}$ in that case. Physically, this linearly growing amplitude arises due to a resonance effect (driving the system at its natural frequency).

You mention $a \to 1$, which makes me think you might also want to understand how the $a \neq 1$ case approaches the $a=1$ case. This is something that confuses students a lot, because it seems like the situation is "discontinuous" when it shouldn't be.

To understand how the two cases come together, you really need to pin down some initial conditions. For example, $z''+z=e^{iax},z(0)=1,z'(0)=0$ has solution $\frac{a^2 \cos(x)-e^{iax}+ia\sin(x)}{a^2-1}$. Computing the limit of this as $a \to 1$ at fixed $x$ requires L'Hospital's rule. Doing that gives the factor of $x$ when you differentiate $e^{iax}$ with respect to $a$.

Comment: as $ a \to 1 \ $ , the particular integral will be the real part of your calculation in the last section which is $ \frac{a^2 \cos x-\cos (ax) }{a^2-1} \ $  Is it ?

Comment: @yourmath That is one particular solution, yes. If you send $a \to 1$ in that, then you recover the solution to $y''+y=\cos(x),y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

a possible particular solution is given by $$y_P=\frac{\cos ^2(x) (-\cos (a x))-\sin ^2(x) \cos (a x)}{a^2-1}$$ now you can consider the case if $a$ tends to $1$

Comment: how did you find the particular integral ? little more steps plz

Answer (score 1):

For $a\neq 1$, we would choose $ P\cos(ax)+Q\sin(ax)$ for our particular solution, and solve for $P$ and $Q$. But if $a=1$, then this form will never solve the particular solution because it is also a solution to the homogeneous equation. The standard strategy in this situation is to multiply the standard form for the particular solution by $x$. So try $$y_p(x)=Px\cos(x)+Qx\sin(x).$$ Then $$y_p''(x)+y_p(x)=-2 P \sin (x)-P x \cos (x)-Q x \sin (x)+2 Q \cos (x)+Px\cos(x)+Qx\sin(x)=2 Q \cos (x)-2 P \sin (x).$$
To make this equal to $\cos(x)$, we require $Q=1/2$ and $P=0$. Therefore, your particular solution is $$y_P(x)=\frac{1}{2}x\sin(x).$$